# How can I click a button and have several other buttons get clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, addeventlistener

I'm very new and just a programming enthusiast so I don't know a lot. I'm building a site where I need to click a button and then have a bunch of other buttons appear clicked. The other buttons don't have any functions when clicked, it's just the change of CSS class to appear "clicked".

So in summary, I need to click the first button, and then on the other side of the page I have 125 buttons which I need to appear "clicked" as well (not all 125, just some). And then when I "unclick" the first button, then they all "unclick" also. It's like toggling some of the buttons with just one.

I have tried any way I know of changing the class of the second buttons when I click the first one. I have tried something like this selecting each individual button by the ID:

```
const gridTriangleOne = document.querySelector('.gridTriangleOne');
const numberTest = document.getElementById('111');

gridTriangleOne.addEventListener('click', myFunction); 

function myFunction() {
numberTest.classList.add('active2');    
};
```

I have tried something like this:

```
const gridTriangleOne = document.querySelector('.gridTriangleOne');
const triangleOne = document.querySelectorAll('.triangleOne');;

gridTriangleOne.addEventListener('click', () =>
    triangleOne.forEach(triangleOne => {
        triangleOne.classList.toggle('active');
    })
);
```

or even a different variation of the above with add instead of toggle. Nothing really works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: share your html as well (or some minimal example that we can run)

Comment: The 2nd code looks like it works, but you have to add some CSS for "active" class. Did you add that in your CSS?

Comment: I did, in fact the active class is already working on all the buttons when I click them because I have another part in the js that just toggles that. But it just doesn't work when I want one click to toggle the other ones.

So essentially, I can click each button individually and they toggle the "active" class, but I can't get it to work when I click the "gridTriangleOne" button for it to toggle the "active" class on all the other buttons that are "triangleOne".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a little cleaner and takes out some unneeded code from the first answer.

```js
document.querySelector(".clickme").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const allPoorElements = document.getElementsByClassName("click");  
  for (let i = 0; i < allPoorElements.length; i++) {
    allPoorElements[i].classList.toggle("clicked");
  }
});
```

```css
.clicked {background-color: #4CAF50;} .clicked, .clickme, .click { background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 32px; font-size: 16px; } .clicked { background-color: lightgreen; border: none; color: black; padding: 16px 32px; font-size: 16px; }
```

```html
<button class="clickme">clickme</button>

<button class="click">1</button>
<button class="click">2</button>
<button class="click">3</button>
<button class="click">4</button>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. I'm sorry for my ignorance, like I said I'm just learning. I see that your solution works here and it does exactly what I need (well I also wanted the "clickme" button to appear "clicked", but that's whatever).

Anyway, I tried it on my program and it still doesn't work. So I'm wondering if I have other foundational errors on my HTML or JS or CSS that I'm just unaware of. I'm not sure if it's because they're on different <div></div> or if it's something else that is causing it not to work, but it's really frustrating.

Comment: But essentially I have the first <div> with 15 buttons, each one of those corresponds to a number and a position from 1-5. So the first button is number 1 position 1, second is number 1 position 2, etc.

The second <div> had the other 125 buttons that correspond to the 3 digit versions, meaning 111, 112, 113, 115, 115, 112, 212, 312, 412, 512, 113, 213... etc. All the way up to 555.

The idea is that when I click the button in the first <div> that corresponds to position 1 number 1, then all the buttons on the second <div> that have a "1" on the first position appear "clicked".

Comment: need to see your actual code to see why it doesn't work

Comment: <div class="symbolGrid" id="symbolGrid">
        <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridTriangleOne">1</button>
    </div>

    <div id="numberList" class="numberList">
        <button class="numberButton" class="triangleOne" class="squareOne" 
        class="circleOne" id="111">111</button>
        <button class="numberButton" class="triangleTwo" class="squareOne" 
        class="circleOne" id="211">211</button>
        <button class="numberButton" class="triangleOne" class="squareOne" 
        class="circleTwo" id="112">112</button>
    </div>

Comment: const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll('.numberButton');

numberButton.forEach(numberButton => {
    numberButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        numberButton.classList.toggle('active');
    
    });
});

const symbolNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.symbolNumber');

symbolNumber.forEach(symbolNumber => {
    symbolNumber.addEventListener('click', () => {
        symbolNumber.classList.toggle('active2');
    
    });
});

Comment: So in the code above it just makes it so that each button I click gets the "active" class or the "active2" class so they appear clicked. All of that works fine, when I click each button it gets formatted with active or active2.

But then when I have tried any of the answers here, it just doesn't work. I see them working here on the "run code snippet" for every answer, it's just that when I transfer to my code it doesn't. IDK why. Sorry for the long posts. I'm new to Stack Overflow as well. Thanks!

Comment: honestly, do you really expect someone to look at your code in a comment?  If you want help faster create a snippet of what you have. The easier you make it for others to help you the more help you will get.

Comment: Sorry, like I said I'm new to all this. I'll try to do the snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the shortest, most efficient way to do it. Hope this helps!

```js
document.querySelector(".clickme").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const allPoorElements = document.getElementsByClassName("click");
  const hasClass = allPoorElements[0].classList.contains("clicked");
  for (let i = 0; i < allPoorElements.length; i++) {
    allPoorElements[i].classList.toggle("clicked", !hasClass);
  }
});
```

```css
.clicked {background-color: #4CAF50;} .clicked, .clickme, .click { background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 32px; font-size: 16px; } .clicked { background-color: lightgreen; border: none; color: black; padding: 16px 32px; font-size: 16px; }
```

```html
<button class="clickme">clickme</button>

<button class="click">1</button>
<button class="click">2</button>
<button class="click">3</button>
<button class="click">4</button>
```

It never hurts to try different approaches and see what works best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for this doesn't run.  When I copy it and place it in a new snippet it seems to be working, at least better.  Take a look here and let me know what's not working for you.  (first snippet doesn't run, second snippet here does)

```js
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll('.numberButton');

numberButton.forEach(numberButton => {
  numberButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    numberButton.classList.toggle('active');

  });
});

const symbolNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.symbolNumber');

symbolNumber.forEach(symbolNumber => {
  symbolNumber.addEventListener('click', () => {
    symbolNumber.classList.toggle('active2');

  });
});

const gridTriangleOne = document.querySelector('.gridTriangleOne');
const triangleOne = document.querySelectorAll('.triangleOne');


const toggleClass = () => {
  triangleOne.forEach(triangleOne => {
    triangleOne.classList.toggle('active');
  });
};

gridTriangleOne.addEventListener('click', toggleClass);
```

```css
.symbolGrid {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 34.5%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  text-indent: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: x-large;
  visibility: visible;
}

.symbolNumber {
  background-color: #ffb25a;
  /* Green background */
  border: 2px solid rgb(104, 104, 104);
  /*Green border */
  color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  /* White text */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  /*Some padding */
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
}

.active2 {
  transform: scale(0.90);
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 22px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #313131;
  color: #a50000;
}

.playPageLogo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 46%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.numberList {
  /*background-color: #3407d6;  Green background */
  /*border: 3px solid rgb(58, 58, 58);  Green border */
  color: rgb(0, 49, 11);
  /* White text */
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  /*Some padding */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left;
  /* Float the buttons side by side */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.numberButton {
  background-color: #6dc595;
  /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /*Green border */
  color: rgb(30, 32, 30);
  /* White text */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 5px 24px;
  /*Some padding */
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left;
  /* Float the buttons side by side */
}


/*.numberList button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders 
  }*/


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

.numberList {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

.numberList button:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
}

.active {
  transform: scale(0.90);
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 22px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #313131;
  color: #a50000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="symbolGrid" id="symbolGrid">

  <h3>&#9650 &#11035 &#11044</h3>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridTriangleOne">1</button>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridSquareOne">1</button>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridCircleOne">1</button><br>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridTriangleTwo">2</button>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridSquareTwo">2</button>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridCircleTwo">2</button><br>
</div>

<div id="numberList" class="numberList">

  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleOne" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="111">111</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleTwo" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="211">211</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleThree" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="311">311</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleFour" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="411">411</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleFive" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="522">511</button><br>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleOne" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="112">112</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleTwo" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="212">212</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleThree" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="312">312</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleFour" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="412">412</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleFive" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="512">512</button><br>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleOne" class="squareOne" class="circleThree" id="113">113</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleTwo" class="squareOne" class="circleThree" id="111">213</button>
</div>
```

```js
const numberButton = document.querySelectorAll('.numberButton');

numberButton.forEach(numberButton => {
  numberButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    numberButton.classList.toggle('active');

  });
});

const symbolNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.symbolNumber');

symbolNumber.forEach(symbolNumber => {
  symbolNumber.addEventListener('click', () => {
    symbolNumber.classList.toggle('active2');

  });
});

const gridTriangleOne = document.querySelector('.gridTriangleOne');
const triangleOne = document.querySelectorAll('.triangleOne');


const toggleClass = () => {
  triangleOne.forEach(triangleOne => {
    triangleOne.classList.toggle('active');
  });
};
```

```css
gridTriangleOne.addEventListener('click', toggleClass);
.symbolGrid {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 34.5%;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  text-indent: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: x-large;
  visibility: visible;
}

.symbolNumber {
  background-color: #ffb25a;
  /* Green background */
  border: 2px solid rgb(104, 104, 104);
  /*Green border */
  color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  /* White text */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  /*Some padding */
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
}

.active2 {
  transform: scale(0.90);
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 22px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #313131;
  color: #a50000;
}

.playPageLogo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 46%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.numberList {
  /*background-color: #3407d6;  Green background */
  /*border: 3px solid rgb(58, 58, 58);  Green border */
  color: rgb(0, 49, 11);
  /* White text */
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  /*Some padding */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left;
  /* Float the buttons side by side */
  visibility: hidden;
}

.numberButton {
  background-color: #6dc595;
  /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /*Green border */
  color: rgb(30, 32, 30);
  /* White text */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 5px 24px;
  /*Some padding */
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left;
  /* Float the buttons side by side */
}


/*.numberList button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders 
  }*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="symbolGrid" id="symbolGrid">

  <h3>&#9650 &#11035 &#11044</h3>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridTriangleOne">1</button>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridSquareOne">1</button>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridCircleOne">1</button><br>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridTriangleTwo">2</button>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridSquareTwo">2</button>
  <button class="symbolNumber" class="gridCircleTwo">2</button><br>
</div>

<div id="numberList" class="numberList">

  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleOne" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="111">111</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleTwo" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="211">211</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleThree" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="311">311</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleFour" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="411">411</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleFive" class="squareOne" class="circleOne" id="522">511</button><br>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleOne" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="112">112</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleTwo" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="212">212</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleThree" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="312">312</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleFour" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="412">412</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleFive" class="squareOne" class="circleTwo" id="512">512</button><br>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleOne" class="squareOne" class="circleThree" id="113">113</button>
  <button class="numberButton" class="triangleTwo" class="squareOne" class="circleThree" id="111">213</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but the second div with the buttons I want to get the "active" class when I click the first 1 button don't even show. I'm not sure if its because I have 2 divs or because of my CSS. In any case, it all works on my VS Code, the part that I need help with is the last part of the JS where I try to get the active class on all the "triangleOne" buttons.

Comment: class = “one two three”  NOT class =“one” class=“two” …

Comment: That was it of course! Thank you so much. Sorry for the back and forth. It works now!

Comment: please accept answer if it works for you.  Thanks.